# session across subdomains not working

Tags: php, session, yii

I want to use cookies & sessions across sub domains. Im strictly using yii architecture. So I did this in cofig.php

```
'session' => array(
            'cookieMode' => 'allow',
            'cookieParams' => array(
                'path' => '/',
                //'domain' => '.mydomain.co',
                'httpOnly' => true,
            ),
        ),
```

I'm getting the cookies across sub domains but not sessions.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314866/session-on-subdomains-still-not-working

Comment: checked but not same question

Comment: Are you really sure YII sessions support cross-subdomain access? If so, please provide the specification you refer to.

Comment: it support cookies then why it wont support session?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to set some PHP/Apache configuration for that.

please add below code at top of file.

```
ini_set("session.cookie_domain", ".domain.com");
```

replace domain.com with your domain.

Comment: set session.cookie_domain value by .htaccess